# What replaces the deprecated AllocMemSize

Tags: delphi, memory-management

I am maintaining a legacy application and I have the following line of code:

```
sb.Panels[3].Text:= ' Memory in use: ' +  IntToStr(AllocMemSize);
```

And it gives the following warning:

```
[dcc32 Warning] BLOB.pas(8242): W1000 Symbol 'AllocMemSize' is deprecated
```

and indeed, AllocMemSize is deprecated (from System.pas):

```
var
  AllocMemSize: Integer deprecated; {Unsupported}
```

My question is this: What is the replacement for `AllocMemSize`?  Is there any point? Is there some other more meaningful measure I can put there?

(I guess I can just delete the call and output entirely, but users apparently want to see this information in the Status Bar)

Comment: A little google search gave this link: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/5/1025020.html, probably not that usefull, but AllocMemSize looks doomed from the beginning...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that conversation - didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call [`GetMemoryManagerState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.GetMemoryManagerState) instead. It returns similar information, although not necessarily distilled down to a single number like `AllocMemSize`. The deprecation is due to Delphi's switch around Delphi 2006 to using FastMM for the memory manager, and it tracks memory differently from the older memory manager.

See also [*Monitoring memory usage*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Monitoring_Memory_Usage) in the documentation.

Comment: So, according this answer I think [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/w3sWfi94) might be used for getting total allocated memory space for (all ?) versions of Delphi.

Comment: I have no way to check, @Tlama. I don't know what compiler version 18 is, but do compilers that old recognize the `$IF` directive?

Comment: At least Delphi 7 does. The `CompilerVersion = 18` means Delphi 2006 compiler.